# minGW (gcc for windows) - Access is denied - a solution or a workaround

Tags: mingw

first I shell explain the background: I would like some python (and other) libs installation on windows to work right, I mean libs that require c compilation in their build process.

since having problem with cygwin and reading some recommendations I've elected to install minGW tools and compiler. after that I've add mingw/bin to the PATH.

when typing gcc from the command line I get: 
Access is denied

If I try gcc-4 or g++ I do get the right response. tried checking the security permissions but it seems that my user has every security permission available
running gcc from minGW shell works right but doesn't solve my basic problem automatic installing of dependencies that have a compilation stage in the build process (since I don't control where it runs from)
Does anyone know a solution or a workaround for this issue?

working with win7 pro 64 bit

Comment: Did you install the mingw-w64-gcc package from the cygwin installer, or did you install the mingw tools manually?

Comment: I also have cygwin but this was installed directly

Comment: You can't call non-cygsin executables from within cygwin. You need to install the cygwin mingw packages to have a cygwin to native Windows cross-compiler.

Comment: but I'm not calling from cygwin -calling directlyfrom windows

Comment: The the question becomes "how did you install and where did you get it?"